# Toast message after MotionEvent

Tags: coordinates, motionevent

I am trying to display the coordinates of a point that a user clicks on the screen using a Toast. its not working in this class for some reasons, can anyone shed some light on why?
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
        {
          //motionevent detects motion from the user
          float x;
          x = event.getX();
          float y;
          y = event.getY();

```
      switch (event.getAction())
      {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //touch_up(x, y);
            invalidate();
            float Cox = event.getX();
            float Coy = event.getY();
            String text = "You clicked at x = " + Cox+ "and y =" + Coy;
            //AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(DrawView.this, text, 10);
            toast.show();

            break;
      }
      return true;
```

Comment: What does your invalidate method do? Maybe move that below everything. Also try getRawX and getRawY instead of just getX and getY

Comment: thanks for your response however, it didnt answer my questions as to why the toast doesnt work. The invalidate method handles the layout view.

Comment: What do u mean it doesn't work? It doesn't show?

Answer (score 0):

Set a class variable called:

```
Context mContext;
```

In onCreate method:

```
mContext = this;
```

Pass this mContext variable in Toast constructor instead of DrawView.this

Comment: nope, still doesnt work.
   when i declare mContext=this; it thorws an error for incompatible types